# How to make CentOS iterate over principals in .k5login (take password for one of them)

Tags: centos, login, kerberos

at my work, we use combination of Debian and newly some CentOS 7 machines. We have a group of kerberos+LDAP servers to provide means of user authentication to another machines. Everything is fine until now.

I was tasked to create a new CentOS7 users webserver which should be kerberized to allow users to log in with their password.
Every webpage should have its own name and a specific group of people should be able to login to manage it.
But it is for normal BFUs so no krb tickets, just passwords!
In Debian still not a problem. Kerberize the server and put a .k5login file containing user principals within home dir of webpage. Then add a `search_k5login` onto the pam_krb5 line in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`.
So I would have something like:

```
/etc/pam.d/common-auth:
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000 search_k5login
```

```
/srv/www/webpage/.k5login:
user1@COMPANY.CZ
user2@COMPANY.CZ
```

With this the Debian takes the password provided by users and try it on those krb principals, so user can login from stupid windows putty/ftp/etc. without even knowing something like krb exists.

But now I need to do this on CentOS7 and can't get something like this working. (logging with krb5 ticket is working without problem)
And it seems if the answer is written somewhere where I can't rech it with my searches.

I have tried:
 - just add the same option to pam
 - study krb5.conf and pam_krb5 manuals
 - waste several hours on unsuccessful search for HowTos/(video)tutorials etc.

Does anybody know how to do this ?

***TL;DR***
I need to get server with:
 - CentOS7
 - krb5 client
 - pam_krb5

To accept login with password and try the password on krb5 principals in `.k5login` file and can't find a way how to do it .

Comment: Check the logs?  Does it say why it's failing?
I assume you added 'search_k5login' into /etc/pam.d/password-auth on the auth line with pam_krb5.so?

Comment: @jsbillings Yes, I tried to add the same option to /etc/pam.d/password-auth in centos. Logs are not helping. The pam_krb5 simply fails with:  
`pam_krb5[26553]: authentication fails for 'webpage' (webpage@COMPANY.CZ): User not known to the underlying authentication module (Client not found in Kerberos database)`
IMHO it does not try the principals in .k5login
(Users for webpages on the debian machine are also not in krb DB)